# How to select a nonblank date

Tags: calendar, powerbi, dax

In power BI, I am computing the percentage difference between Stock price index levels over the last year.

```
 Ann pch = 

VAR __EarliestValue =   CALCULATE(SUM('Equity Markets (2)'[Value]),
                         DATEADD(LASTDATE('Calendar'[Date]),-1,YEAR))

VAR __LastDateValue = CALCULATE(SUM('Equity Markets (2)'[Value]),
                        LASTDATE('Calendar'[Date]))

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(__LastDateValue,__EarliestValue) -1)
```

The above is correct but there is a bug: some dates fall on the weekend, or other non-trading days, in which case I want to select the next nonblank value for `__EarliestValue` and the previous nonblank value in the case of `__LastDateValue`.

Could anyone suggest the code to implement this.

I am very much a DAX/Power BI novice. Thank you very much.

Data Sample:

[image: S&P]

[image: calendar]

[image: relationships]

Comment: I wonder if your calculation works at all: DateAdd is used as filter but will never return anything because you have as input one date? Can you give some sample data, I think I can help you..

Comment: Thanks. I don't know of a good way of sharing data, I dumped in some screenshots. The code wasn't QA'd exhaustively but seemed correct - other than the bug...

Answer (score 1):

I created a slicer based on the column 'Equity Markets(2)'[Date].

*note: Do not make the slicer on your calendar date, then you get your "holes"*

Then I created a measure with following formula:

```
Measure = LOOKUPVALUE(EquityMarkets[Value];EquityMarkets[Date]; MAX(EquityMarkets[Date]))/ LOOKUPVALUE(EquityMarkets[Value];EquityMarkets[Date]; MIN(EquityMarkets[Date]))
```

This measure I show in the card visual. The result is when using the slicer, the calculation is made.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. This is a great workaround, but it’s not what I’m looking for. I want the panel to compute annual change from the current date, rather than manually set the slicer.  
A second issue is the robustness of using the date in the table, rather than the calendar – I have other tables which I want to drive commonly- but they may have unique individual dates. For this reason I’m anxious to write code driven by the calendar table.