# DAX Select a date range in the calendar table

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I am looking to select the size of the calendar table, filtering everything before or after some date, much like a slicer does.

I am trying to compute the percentage change between prices of equity indexes between two dates: now and a  year ago. The problem is that the same date last year   sometimes falls on a non-trading day. In that case I want the code to select the earliest value available.

In a similar situation, where I use a slicer, I implemented this by using `FIRSTNONBLANK` and `LASTNONBLANK` functions. This way, if the slicer is set to a non-trading date the system still works.

I am very much a DAX/Power BI novice, interested in the methodology in DAX as much as addressing the current problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a nonblank date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56335951/how-to-select-a-nonblank-date)

Comment: I just answered your original question, please remove this duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch! The two questions are indeed about two different implementations which would solve the same problem.